Error [ERR_REQUIRE_CYCLE_MODULE]: Cannot require() ES Module...but I'm not
Trying to run my node app, with node main.js, but getting this error: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_CYCLE_MODULE]: Cannot require() ES Module. I have also tried node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node main.js.
My main.js file imports things from './schema/index.js' using regular esm syntax, like: import { importName } from './schema/index.js'. I am not using require, so not sure why it's accusing me of that.
Full error shown below.
What am I doing wrong here?
→ node main.js
node:internal/modules/esm/loader:315
        throw new ERR_REQUIRE_CYCLE_MODULE(message);
              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_CYCLE_MODULE]: Cannot require() ES Module /path/to/app/schema/index.js in a cycle. (from /path/to/app/noop.js)
    at ModuleLoader.importSyncForRequire (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:315:15)
    at loadESMFromCJS (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1547:5)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1677:16)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:219:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:138:16) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_CYCLE_MODULE'
}

Node.js v22.12.0


PS. There is no file called noop.js, and I have no idea what that part means!! Has anyone seen this before?
package.json:
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {},
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.3",
  "module": "./main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./main.js"
}


I have the same problem trying to run node as ESM modules inside a docker container.
CMD ["--experimental-loader", "./.pnp.loader.mjs", "./packages/my-pacakge/dist/main.js"]

Package import doesn't work this way for nodejs in case of nodejs working I write below first of all install your package and then import nodejs main file an then using import package module.
main.js
   const importName = require("schema/index.js");

this is the way for import external code there is your javascript import and create module syntax not working
